# Drawing relationship lines in the view between 2 objects via Python - possible?

Tags: python, add-on

If there are 2 objects in the scene, one has a custom property with the name of another object, is it possible to draw a colored solid or dotted line between those two in 3D/ortho view ?

Looks like this would be something related to the question:

```
bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
bgl.glColor4f(r, g, b, 1.0)
bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_LINE_STRIP)
bgl.glVertex2i(x0, y0)
bgl.glVertex2i(x1, y1)
bgl.glEnd()
```

but I wonder if that will still work with viewport drawing code update.

Comment: Have you tried it? You say you "wonder"

Comment: I haven't, that's why I wonder :)